# Sending SMS through Twilio and C#

Tags: c#, sms, twilio

We are building a ASP.NET MVC app, which requires SMS integration. I have downloaded the latest pre-release  (through nuget) and used the source code as mentioned in API section. However, it seems to have an issue

```
var message = twilio.SendMessage(...); 
Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);...
```

Where the `Sid` is not available in the `message` object. Instead I am using `Status`.

The actual problem is when I try to send as per the guidelines and API tokens available in the SMS testing page, I got the message.Status as "Faulted" and no SMS was sent. Even I tried with the test page @ https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer/message-create, that too didn't send a message indeed.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

What .NET version is your application?  The pre-release nuget package includes two different assemblies, one for .NET 4 and greater, one for .NET 3.5.

If your project is using .NET 4 or greater all of the library methods are new async, so your call to send message would look like:

```
var result = await twilio.SendMessage(...);
Console.WriteLine(result.Sid);
```

Hope that helps.